# How to append Json.obj into Json.arr Scala?

Tags: arrays, json, scala

I am newbie to **Scala**.

I want to append **Json.obj** into **Json.arr** during runtime in Scala.

**Json Object:**

```
var x: JsValue = Json.obj("name" -> "Fiver", "age" -> 4,"role" -> JsNull)
```

**Json Array:**

```
var y: JsValue = Json.arr(x)
```

Here, I am able to append single Json.obj to Json.arr but I want to add multiple Json.obj to Json.arr dynamically.

I can do like this:

```
var y: JsValue = Json.arr(
Json.obj("name" -> "Fiver", "age" -> 4,"role" -> JsNull), 
Json.obj("name" -> "Fiver", "age" -> 4,"role" -> JsNull)
)
```

but it is **not** appending in one by one. I want to append **Json.Obj** dynamically.

Comment: I assume you are using a library? Is it the Json Play Lib?

Comment: `Json.arr` is expected a vararg `JsValueWrapper*` and `JsArray` is accepting a `Seq[JsValue]`, both can be prepared "dynamically". What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to scala! :)

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
val x: JsValue = Json.obj("name" -> "Fiver", "age" -> 4,"role" -> JsNull)

val y: JsArray = Json.arr()

val res = y :+(x) 

println(res)
```

The output will be `[{"name":"Fiver","age":4,"role":null}]`

I found the necessary method to append a JsValue to a JsArray in the play documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsArray

As a side note: only use `var` when you intend for that variable to be updated later on. Use `val` when your value will not change during the coarse of your program. It is considered good style to use `var` sparingly.

Comment: Thanks.. `val res = y:+(x)` it adds only one `Json.obj` but it need to append `Json.obj()` into `val y`. So, I tried ` y = y :+(x)`. It worked! Is it correct way? If yes, would you update your answer ? Please update it, I'll mark it as correct (lol)